# Pronunciation of "объясняет"

Tags: произношение, редукция-гласных

What's the right way to pronounce **объясняет**? My guess would be something like '**обшсняет**' (I'm having a hard time with the hard sign). This is word is somewhat similar to "**Eichhörnchen**" by the way, it's actually real subtle. I'd appreciate an English word with an equivalent sound as an example.

Comment: did you mean "обйсняет" (I hardly can imagine you've intentionally used "ш" - it correspond to "sch" in German.

Comment: Trey, can you share an audio of your progress? But please don't feel obliged.

Comment: @shabunc sorta, after hearing the pronunciation over and over I guess **бйсняет** is indeed a better approximation

Comment: [аб'й'ис'н'ай'ит]. Learn Russian transcription system (phonological analysis). The stress on the second a.

Comment: @Anixx can you indicate some good resources?

Comment: Something like ub-yis-NYI-it.

Comment: To me hard signs are easy: "ъ" indicates that the next vowel is pronounced as if it is the first letter in the word (and the preceding consonat is pronounced as if it is at the end of the word). That said, in everyday speach "я" after "объ" sounds more like "е", at least in Moscow region.

Comment: `and the preceding consonat is pronounced as if it is at the end of the word` - this might not be accurate, since finals are devoiced in Russian, and if it were true `об-` would have to be incorrectly pronounced `оп-`

Comment: @Annixx [ʌбjиес'н'а́jьт]. I assume you didn't study phonetics at the university (professionally)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to divide it into two separate parts, the prefix `об-` pronounced as `аб-` and `-яснЯет` pronounced as `йисьнЯит`. Try to pronounce them separately, then combine the two parts back together - `aбйисьнЯит`.

I believe `ш` you hear because of the sound `j` subtly present in the phoneme `й`, but it's by far not as voiced as in the German `-ig`

I unfortunately can't think of any similar sounding word in English. Well, may be `object`, and only because in Russian it is also spelled with the "hard sign" following the combination `об` - `объЕкт` (pronounced `абйЕкт`), only that in this word it's not a prefix (at least not of Russian origin).

Comment: Can you show where the stress is?

Answer (score 4):

**ub-yis-NIA-it** (with NIA stressed)

- **ub** as in pub
- **yis** as in yeast
- **NIA** has *one* vowel sound (not a diphthong): a soft N followed by A
- **it** as in it :)

You can think of the Ъ as the **y** sound in **yes** or **yeast**. Same goes for Ь in front of a vowel: бульон, пасьянс.

You might like this website: http://russiangram.com It transcribes Russian words using English spelling rules. It doesn't do vowel reduction yet.